# Qt subprojects and TDD

Tags: qt, unit-testing, tdd, qt-creator

I am building a Qt application which consists of several components (including plugins). Each sub project contains several classes. 
I want to use the "normal" TDD workflow in my development process - namely;

1. I write a new function/method of a class in a module as a test
2. Compile the test (which should fail) for that module
3. Modify the source to correct the error (by adding the func/method etc)
4. Write test cases for the new function/method
5. Modify the src code to fix tests that fail

Each sub project will contain a src/ and test/ folders which will hold the source files and unittests respectively

This is what the project directory structure looks like:

```
myapp
|
|-myapp.pro
|
|--module1/
|     |-src/
|     |-test/
|
|--module2/
|     |-src/
|     |-test/
|
.
.
|--moduleN/
|     |-src/
|     |-test/
```

How can I setup QCreator so that I can build a subproject or its unittest from the QCreator GUI?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `subdirs` project and add the subprojects to its .pro file :

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

CONFIG += ordered

SUBDIRS += \
    module1 \
    module2 \
    ...
    moduleN \
    myapp
```

You should bring the subprojects that others depend on, first in the list. Also notice that the name of the .pro file of the subproject should be the same as it's folder name. This way the subprojects are detected and listed in the Projects pane.

The subprojects `module1`, `module2` ... `moduleN` could be libraries which have `TEMPLATE = lib` in their .pro file and `myapp` should be app containing `TEMPLATE = app` in the .pro file.

You can use the libraries in each subproject by linking it to the subproject. This can be done by right clicking on the subproject and choosing `Add Library` and then `Internal Library`. When you select one library from the list of subprojects, the linking configurations are added to the .pro automatically. It will be like :

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../module1/release/ -lmodule1
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../module1/debug/ -lmodule1
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../Base/ -lmodule1

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../module1
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../module1
```

Comment: Thanks The approach you suggest would result in the project (say a module) and it's tests to exist side by side (at the same directory level). What I want to do is to have BOTH the source and it's tests under a parent. I suppose I can create a parent or container project of template SUBDIR and have that contain two projects (the actual source and the unit tests)  live side by side. For such a sophisticated piece of software  (Qt), having  to resort to this kind of kludge /hackery is very ugly to say the least.  There has to be a better way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `subdirs` template in .pro file.

I believe, you can start from following [link](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-project-creating.html) (at the bottom of linked page).